# optimising tweenlite for IPhone Flash application

Tags: iphone, flash, ios

I have an intro screen with a bitmap 250x130 that i want to fade in and out. 
I am using tweenlite and it looks great on the Pc, but on the iphone, it looks
like 1 or 2 fps, really slow.
There is only 2 text fields and this animating Bitmap. The movie is set to the 
default 24fps. the code is

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

public class intro extends MovieClip {


    public function intro() {
        fadesIn();
    }

    function fadesOut():void{ if (this.visible) TweenLite.to(mc, 4, {delay:1,ease:Cubic.easeInOut, alpha:0,onComplete:fadesIn});}
    function fadesIn():void{ if (this.visible) TweenLite.to(mc, 4, {delay:1,ease:Cubic.easeInOut, alpha:1,onComplete:fadesOut});}

}
```

}

iphone rendering is GPU. I have stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW; on the 1st frame.

thanks

Comment: cacheAsBitmap = true ? Haven't tried iPhone packager btw.

Comment: is the alpha changing deleting it from the cache maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Starling (http://gamua.com/starling/) is sometimes the only way to get good performance on mobile since it fully uses the GPU on devices.

From the Adobe site (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d719af412b2b394529-8000.html):

> Enable hardware graphics acceleration in an AIR application by
>   including gpu in the application descriptor
>   (or use direct to leverage Stage3D). You
>   cannot change render modes at runtime. On desktop computers, using
>   gpu will fallback to
>   direct.
>
> Note: In order to leverage GPU acceleration of Flash content with AIR
>   for mobile platforms, Adobe recommends that you use
>   renderMode="direct" (that is, Stage3D) rather than renderMode="gpu".
>   Adobe officially supports and recommends the following Stage3D based
>   frameworks: Starling (2D) and Away3D (3D). For more details on Stage3D
>   and Starling/Away3D, see http://gaming.adobe.com/getstarted/.

It is also worth noting that cacheAsBitmap does not work if the object is being alpha'd.

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3cacheasbitmap/

> You should note that the cacheAsBitmap property is very restricted and
>   will only use the bitmap cached when the object is static, or moved
>   vertically or horizontally across the stage. If you attempt to rotate
>   the object, change its scale, change its alpha property or attempt to
>   do anything else with it other than changing its shape, the player
>   would have to recalculate the shape of the vector and then draw the
>   bitmap version again for each single step in the transformation. If
>   you apply cacheAsBitmap to an object that is continuously rotating or
>   is being animated in anyway other than changes its x or y property,
>   the process would consume more processing power than the original
>   vector graphic because not only the vector would have to be calculated
>   for each step in the animation, but the bitmap would also have to be
>   drawn for every single step in the animation making the system do
>   double the job!

Answer (score 1):

Performance considerations are a bit different for an iOS cross compiled app then they are for a native flash app, due to the differences in how they render graphics and process the timeline.

Here is some extra reading for optimizing for iOS cross-compilation.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/optimize_content_ios.html

http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=986

Mostly it involves bitmap caching, accurate and efficient bounds measurement (especially important when using Flex), and making sure your Actionscript is as optimized as possible.